# Black space after HTML ends

Tags: javascript, html, css

So , I have gotten a ticket from a client saying that he has some extra space after the footer end,i looked into it and it's true,basically,after the HTML ends there are a good few scrolls of plain black space. I tried giving the html doc a height of 100% and body a min-height:100% ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does you browser's dev tools show you about the source of this extra space?

Comment: It shows nothing, html basically ends after footer.

Comment: I get a lot of DOM errors in my browser console

Comment: Hmm,I can't seem to can't get this right, I don't exactly know what's causing the problem, any ideeas how can i find out ?

Comment: Looking at the site, I would *suspect* the "privacy" thing with `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` since, allowing for the fixed menu, it appears to be very close to an entire screen height extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the `overflow` of the `div class="page-width"` in the `footer class="site-footer"` is causing this issue. Set the css property `overflow: hidden;` to resolve the issue.

The implemented change:

```
.page-width {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked, i just found the exact same answer 1min before you posting. Still,props to you sir :)

Comment: Kudos!! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that is shown from the dev tools that you have included in the HTML tag and has classes as follows html.js.svg.supports.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.shopify-features.__smart-payment-buttons--enabled.gr__virtualbabylon_com that has a dimension of 1349*2357.11. One of those classes or a combination of them generate that height of 2357.11. That is where you should start looking at.